# How do you change the sort order of items using PowerShell

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have some items created using `New-Item` but they are automatically sorted alphabetically. I would much prefer these items to be sorted by *Created* date.

How do you change the sort order of items using SPE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two places I can think of when it comes to changing the sort order.

### Item level sort order

Select an item and change the view in the ribbon to include *Standard fields*. You should see something like this:

[image: Sortorder]

These values can be changed from the ribbon or programmatically and the value is an integer (e.g. 100, 200).

**Example:** The following changes an item's sort order. Assumes you know the precise order you want to achieve.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{C9CB2B73-04B3-43F8-B36A-D64C77E35F79}"
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item.Fields["__Sortorder"].Value = 200
$item.Editing.EndEdit() > $null
```

### Subitem level sort order

This is likely the option you want to go with. You don't have to worry about changing the sort manually every time, and it goes beyond a simple numerical value.

[image: Subitem sorting context menu]

[image: Sort order menu]

**Example:** The following sets the sort order on the parent node which results in this behavior cascading to the immediate children.

```powershell
function Set-SortOrder {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="SortOrder")]
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [item]$Item,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="SortOrder")]
        [ValidateSet("Created","Default","Display name","Logical","Reverse","Updated")]
        [string]$SortOrder,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Reset")]
        [switch]$Reset
    )

    $subitemsSortOrderFieldId = "{6FD695E7-7F6D-4CA5-8B49-A829E5950AE9}"

    $sortValue = & { 
        switch($SortOrder) {
            "Created" {
                "{C1FF011E-B02A-44E3-8444-9FC89CFC28CE}"
            }
            "Default" {
                "{781247D2-9785-400F-8935-C818EC757967}"
            }
            "Display name" {
                "{44D1A0D2-E17B-4DAA-ADDF-53F2E8F58525}"
            }
            "Logical" {
                "{EA1DECB2-B4F2-4AE0-99A8-30FDED9B8B50}"
            }
            "Reverse" {
                "{C3E3F0E3-0162-4F1F-AB3E-40348E371A3F}"
            }
            "Updated" {
                "{32416A95-4197-4D33-8CE7-7BB4FFEBEB42}"
            }
        }
    }

    $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
    if($Reset.IsPresent) {
        $item.Fields[$subitemsSortOrderFieldId].Reset()
    } else {
        $item.Fields[$subitemsSortOrderFieldId].Value = $sortValue
    }
    $item.Editing.EndEdit() > $null
}

$item = Get-item -Path "master:" -ID "{A1D0B3BC-CCDA-41FF-B59A-33AB84BF950B}"
# Reset the subitem sorting to Standard values
Set-SortOrder -Item $item -Reset
# Change the subitem sorting to based on Created Date
Set-SortOrder -Item $item -SortOrder Created
```